# Unable to update mimeType using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I've loaded some files to Google Drive, but mistakenly assigned an incorrect mimeType to some of the files. I now want to update the mimeType to be the correct value.

I have the following Python code, which successfully updates the description associated with the file, but the mimeType always retains its original value.

```
file = service.files().get(fileId=GoogleFileId).execute()
file['mimeType'] = 'application/msword'
file['description'] = 'test description'
updated_file = service.files().update(fileId=file['id'], body=file, updateViewedDate=False).execute()
```

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Dave

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll have to update the file content itself. The mimeType is calculated from the file that got uploaded. Do it by passing a `media_body`, etc that you used to create the file.

It's a nuisance to do, sorry. But if you are scripting it, it should cause you too much pain for "some files".

Comment: Thanks Ali, so basically I can retrieve the contents from Drive using the downloadUrl for example, and use this in the media_body in the update.